# I can not return access token in JWT SPRINGBOOT V2.2.0 OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt

I have a hard time on a personal study project. Difficulty implementing oauth2, whenever I try to get access token it returns me

```
2019-11-19 22:01:35.398 ERROR 4705 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:448) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:449) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]

2019-11-19 22:01:35.426  WARN 4705 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for POST /error
```

> my project uses Version Spring Boot v2.2.0.RELEASE and Java 1.8

**Application.propeties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test123
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 3600000
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**AuthorizationServerConfig**

```
 @Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("angular")
                    .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("angular"))
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(1800)
                    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600 * 24)
                    .and()
                    .withClient("admin")
                    .secret("admin")
                    .scopes("read")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(1800)
                    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600 * 24);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                    .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                    .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }


        @Bean
        public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
            JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
            accessTokenConverter.setSigningKey("financas");
            return accessTokenConverter;
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
        }

    }
```

**ResourceServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/pagamento").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.stateless(true);
    }
    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return super.userDetailsService();
    }

}
```

> now my refresh token classes

**RefreshTokenPostProcessor**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RefreshTokenPostProcessor implements ResponseBodyAdvice<OAuth2AccessToken> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return returnType.getMethod().getName().equals("postAccessToken");
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken beforeBodyWrite(OAuth2AccessToken body,
      MethodParameter methodParameter, MediaType mediaType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass,
                                             ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        HttpServletRequest req =  ((ServletServerHttpRequest)request).getServletRequest();
        HttpServletResponse resp = ((ServletServerHttpResponse)response).getServletResponse();

        DefaultOAuth2AccessToken token = (DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) body;

            String refreshToken = body.getRefreshToken().getValue();
            adicionaRefreshTokenNoCookie(refreshToken, req, resp);
            removerRefreshTokenDoBody(token);
        return body;
    }

    private void removerRefreshTokenDoBody(DefaultOAuth2AccessToken token) {
        token.setRefreshToken(null);
    }

    private void adicionaRefreshTokenNoCookie(String refreshToken, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        Cookie refreshTokenCookie = new Cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken);
        refreshTokenCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        refreshTokenCookie.setSecure(false); //TODO: change in production
        refreshTokenCookie.setPath(req.getContextPath() + "/oauth/token");
        refreshTokenCookie.setMaxAge(2592000);
        resp.addCookie(refreshTokenCookie);
    }

}
```

**RefreshTokenPreProcessorFilter**

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RefreshTokenPreProcessorFilter implements Filter {


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        if ("/oauth/token".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getRequestURI())
                && "refresh_token".equals(req.getParameter("grant_type"))
                && req.getCookies() != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : req.getCookies()) {
                if (cookie.getName().equals("refreshToken")) {
                    String refreshToken = cookie.getValue();
                    req = new MyServletRequestWrapper(req, refreshToken);
                }
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    static class MyServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        private String refreshToken;

        public MyServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, String refreshToken) {
            super(request);
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
            ParameterMap<String, String[]> map = new ParameterMap<>(getRequest().getParameterMap());
            map.put("refresh_token", new String[] {refreshToken});
            map.setLocked(true);
            return map;
        }
    }

}
```

**SpringBootApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@WebAppConfiguration
public class FinancaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FinancaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

*`Remembering that my authentication is in the database and I am using PasswordEncoder on the database password and authentication passwords, I would like some help setting up the server and where my error is because I cannot generate an access token, the error returned is just this one in the console. thankful`*

Answer (score 1):

I like your code Felipe - it's a very nicely written API - the problem is that it attempts to issue tokens also, which an API should not do.

I'd recommend walking through my tutorial, to understand the roles of API, UI and Authorization Server:
https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/

Once you've done that I think you'll be able to adapt your API and fix your own problems - feel free to post back any follow up questions though.

Answer (score 0):

In the real world almost all companies use a third party (cloud) system as the Authorization Server:
https://authguidance.com/2019/09/15/developer-domain-setup/

You will learn OAuth much faster this way - and it is free.

You then only need to focus on integrating your APIs and UIs with standards compliant endpoints like this:
https://authguidance.com/2019/03/24/java-spring-boot-api-oauth-coding/

Happy to answer follow up questions if it helps ..

Comment: Hello friend, I just sent the project to github, maybe it is easier to identify the error, if possible take a look please ..

Thank you very much

https://github.com/felipeesc/financa